# Pitfalls of using only two diodes in a "full wave rectifier"?

Tags: diodes, rectifier, full-bridge

Scenario:
I have a small signal from a Piezo element which I am amplifying using a fully differential amplifier. Thus, my gained output from this In-amp are "two" (sine) waves inverse of each other (or 180 out of phase). These are not shown on the schematic as it exceeds the scope of the question.

To complicate matters, I am designing the system to use only positive voltage references. Thus, my output from the diff amp is centered around +2.5V.

Size is a huge portion of this project so I am trying to use as few components as possible.

I put together a "rectifier" of sorts using only 2 high-speed schottky diodes. Basically simple concept(s) as a regular full bridge. Obviously simulation only holds so much water--but the early results seem promising. Though, this "seem too simple" am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: This seems like the same thing as a full-wave rectifier using a center-tapped transformer, no?

Comment: The "missing diff amp" may be poorly simulated as two perfect voltage sources (V1 & V2 in your schematic). Are you sure that their outputs have no DC offset from the assumed 2.5V? Will this rectifier *really be loaded* by 10M, with no associated capacitance?

Comment: Why are you using a 'fully differential' amplifier? _"Size is a huge portion of this project so I am trying to use as few components as possible."_ - Full bridge Schottky rectifiers are available in small packages eg. ROHM FMN1 https://www.rohm.com/products/diodes/switching-diodes/standard/fmn1-product

Comment: Output waveform is unbelievable. What model are you using for the MBRS260?

Comment: I am using components very similar to what may or may not specifically be implemented in a final circuit. Obviously the library doesn't contain everything. But here is the schematic using the differential amp planned to implement (LT1994). https://imgur.com/a/fTFoG03

Comment: @Bruce, I concur, but could you clarify in how you would see the waveform realistically behaving? I'd expect more slip in the turnaround given the Vf of real diodes

Comment: So R1 is actually 10k, not 10meg, and now the waveform makes more sense. Exactly why do you need to rectify the wave?